# Android CollapsingToolbarLayout issue without ImageView

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

[image]

Above **screenshot** you can see there is two **images blue and pink**

1. Blue is single image it's a **ImageView**
2. Pink is slider of images its **FrameLayout with ViewPager**

The **problem** is when i use **ImageView** then **toolbar become transparent** and Image set to **background** of **toolbar** for example blue image.

when I remove ImageView then it become **gray** and **FrameLayout** will not attached to **background of toolbar like blue image** find  the screenshot below

[image]

here is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:stateListAnimator="@anim/appbar_always_elevated"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:titleEnabled="false"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
       

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/test"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">


                        <include layout="@layout/layout_slider" />


                    </FrameLayout>




        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:titleMarginTop="15dp" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**layout_slider.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/view_slider_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<FrameLayout
    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/slider_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/slider_height">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect_gray"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_very_small"
                android:text="Published Apps and Courses"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center|center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="38dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>



</FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I don't want **blue image**. I **showed** you just **for example** if I use **ImageView** then it's attaching to background of toolbar when I use other **view** it's not

Please help

Comment: can you show layout_slider's xml?

Comment: i have updated my question